Building a c# dll project throwing a MSB3061 warning
I’m building a C# dll library project, that creates the dll file and registers it with Windows Registry. The build process is infact generating the dll and registering the dll, but throwing the following MSB3061 warning.
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(5823,5): warning MSB3061: Unable to delete file “C:\Users\Madhu\Documents\repos\MyCtrl\bin\Debug\MyCtrl.dll”. Access to the path ‘C:\Users\Madhu\Documents\repos\MyCtrl\bin\Debug\MyCtrl.dll’ is denied.
Now, I’m getting this warning even with when I open Visual Studio as Admin. The bin and descending folders have write/modify access to both user account and Admin user account. I’m using Visual Studio Professional 2022 (64-bit) Version 17.11.5 on a Windows 10 machine. I understand this is a warning, but since the dll will be distributed across multiple servers, I’d like to understand the reason for the warning, and if there is a way to mitigate that, without supressing it. Thank you for your time and advise ahead.
.NET
web

Tried running Visual Studio in Admin mode and the user an Admin user have Write/Modify rights on bin and child folders.
This is what I'm calling for Register() [ComRegisterFunction()] 
public static void Register(Type t) { 
  try { 
    if (OperatingSystem.IsWindows()) { 
 
 ActiveXCtrlHelper.RegasmRegisterControl(t); 
    } 
  } 
  catch (Exception ex) { 
    throw; 
  } 
} 

// Definition of RegasmRegisterControl()

public static void RegasmRegisterControl(Type t)
{
    // Check the argument
    GuardNullType(t, "t");
    GuardTypeIsControl(t);

    // Open the CLSID key of the control
    using (RegistryKey keyCLSID = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(
        @"CLSID\" + t.GUID.ToString("B"), true))
    {
        RegistryKey subkey = null;
        subkey = keyCLSID.OpenSubKey("InprocServer32", true);
        if (subkey != null)
        {
            try
            {
                string strAssemblyPath = IsNetCore() ? GetLatestNetCoreRuntimePath() + @"\coreclr.dll" : Environment.SystemDirectory + @"\mscoree.dll";
                if (System.IO.File.Exists(strAssemblyPath))
                {
                    subkey.SetValue(null, strAssemblyPath);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception) {}
        }

        using (subkey = keyCLSID.CreateSubKey("Control")) {; };

        using (subkey = keyCLSID.CreateSubKey("MiscStatus"))
        {
            int nMiscStatus = OLEMISC_RECOMPOSEONRESIZE +
                OLEMISC_CANTLINKINSIDE + OLEMISC_INSIDEOUT +
                OLEMISC_ACTIVATEWHENVISIBLE + OLEMISC_SETCLIENTSITEFIRST;
            subkey.SetValue("", nMiscStatus.ToString(), RegistryValueKind.String);
        }

        using (subkey = keyCLSID.CreateSubKey("ToolBoxBitmap32"))
        {
            subkey.SetValue("", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location + ", 101",
                RegistryValueKind.String);
        }

        using (subkey = keyCLSID.CreateSubKey("TypeLib"))
        {
            Guid libId = AssemblyExtenstions.GetTypeLibGuidForAssembly(t.Assembly);
            subkey.SetValue("", libId.ToString("B"), RegistryValueKind.String);
        }

        using (subkey = keyCLSID.CreateSubKey("Version"))
        {
            int nMajor, nMinor;
            AssemblyExtenstions.GetTypeLibVersionForAssembly(t.Assembly, out nMajor, out nMinor);
            subkey.SetValue("", String.Format("{0}.{1}", nMajor, nMinor));
        }

    }
}

Since GetTypeLibVersionForAssembly() and GetTypeLibGuidForAssembly() are not available in .Net Core, I wrote extended functions to add Custom Attributes to cast them as GuidAttribute and AssemblyVersionAttribute

Check that the dll file is not in use while the build is running.

u need to unreg the library everytime before u recompile

If you navigate to the folder "“C:\Users\Madhu\Documents\repos\MyCtrl\bin\Debug", can you delete manually  the file "MyCtrl.dll"?

It's very likely that the DLL is in use by another process probably via the COM registration. (The Sysinternals Suite has tools that can help including the Process Explorer GUI tool and the ListDLLs CLI tool.) You should consider never registering on the output folder (bin\Debug, bin\Release), adding a publish/deploy step, and only registering on the deployment folder.

Also never register on a build server. Deploy and register on a virtual or dedicated unit test server. COM registrations are global to the machine. You can't test different builds of the DLL in different processes on the same machine.

@DouXu-MSFT, Yes I can delete the dll file manually.

@OldBoy, the dll is not in use while building

@JonathanDodds, will look into it.

@Alander, Its unregistering before build.

tbh this task is supposed to be upgrading the target framework from .Net 4.7 to .Net Core 8.  Its build ing and registering the dll fine in .Net 4.7. But I guess since .Net Core is OS independent, and the registering process is slightly different with .Net Core (coreclr instead of regsvr32), its throwing that warning.

What registration are you trying to do in .NET 8? COM is not supported and the MSBuild tasks RegisterAssembly and UnregisterAssembly just report an error.

This is what I'm calling for Register()
[ComRegisterFunction()]
public static void Register(Type t)
{
try {
if (OperatingSystem.IsWindows())
{
ActiveXCtrlHelper.RegasmRegisterControl(t);
}
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
throw;
}
}

Could you  use Resource Monitor to check if "MyCtrl.dll" is being used by  another process,?
